# Unable to install tidyr in R version 3.1.1

Tags: r, failed-installation, installation-package, tidyr

I am unable to install `tidyr` package in R version 3.1.1

This is what happens:

```
install.packages("tidyr")

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Name/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tidyr’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)
```

I have a Windows PC and have just installed `dplyr` which got installed easily and is running smoothly.

Any ideas why this is happening as this doesn't seem to be a general issue.

Comment: What mirror are you using?  You could try downloading http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/tidyr_0.2.0.zip and installing using the local copy ... What are the results of `available.packages()["tidyr",]` ?

Comment: Can you provide `Sys.info()` ?

Answer (score 7):

I think the problem lies with the newest version of dplyr (0.4.2) that requires R ≥ 3.1.2. I solved the issue by using an older version of dplyr and installing all packages from the 0-Cloud repository.

```
install.packages("assertthat")
install.packages("magrittr")
install.packages("lazyeval")
install.packages("BH")
install.packages("R6")
install.packages("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dplyr/dplyr_0.4.1.tar.gz", repos=NULL)
install.packages("tidyr")
```

Comment: For RevoREnt7.3.0 R3.1.1, `tidyr` is compatible with `dplyr`0.4.1. The above solution proved useful in the environment I specified.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue using R 3.3.3. Load library(dplyr) then install.packages('tidyr').

Or

Try closing and restarting R, then give it another go.

Answer (score 1):

I got same Problem with `DSR` Package, like this:

`(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘DSR’ is not available (for R version 3.2.4 Revised)`

then solved it with `devtoolls`.

`devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyr")`